# Bot Framework - how to add same field multiple times in FormFlow

Tags: botframework

I need to display same field multiple times to the user. I inherited a code which uses FormFlow to build the dialog. It displays the field once but ignores the second time and moves to the next field. Simplistic code looks like this

```
return new FormBuilder<TestClass>()
                .Field(nameof(TestClass.Field1))
                .Field(nameof(TestClass.Field2))
                .Field(nameof(TestClass.Field3), "Is User busy? {||}")
                .Field(nameof(TestClass.Field4))
                .Field(nameof(TestClass.Field3), "Is User busy? {||}")
                .Field(nameof(TestClass.Field5))
                .Build();
```

Field3 is displayed once but it is ignored second time and bot display field5 after field4. I have tried setting field3 to null in field4 validator. Is there any easy way to achieve displaying same field multiple times using FormFlow?

Comment: Not sure if this makes sense. Once FormFlow ask for a field and the user provides a value, FormFlow skip it (on purpose). If you explain the real scenario, maybe we can come up with a better implementation

Comment: This bot is to give a feeback about certain service - if user is giving too many garbage responses, the requirement is to ask user if he would like to give feeback later? If he says no, the bot has to continue with the next question. if user says yes - he/she is busy, bot has to quit.